# Making A QPushButton round C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpushbutton, qrect

I'm trying a code to make a **`QPushButton`** looking **round** , this code seems to be working, but after execution , it show me only the **half** of the ellipse, can anybody help me to figure out why is show only the **half** of it, its about the **`m_bouton1`** ?

I did before checked this link [Change rectangular Qt button to round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734319/change-rectangular-qt-button-to-round)

But its not working , it appears only the half of it.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "MyFenetre.h"
#include "MyWindow.h"

MyFenetre::MyFenetre() : QWidget()
{
    setFixedSize(300, 150);

    m_bouton = new QPushButton("Salut", this);
    m_bouton->setFont(QFont("Comic Sans MS", 14));
    m_bouton->move(110, 50);

    m_bouton1=new QPushButton("Boutton RounD (*)");
    m_bouton1->setFixedHeight(200);
    m_bouton1->setFixedWidth(200);

    QRect *rect = new QRect(0,0,190,190);

    qDebug() << rect->size();
    qDebug() << m_bouton1->size();

    QRegion *region = new QRegion(*rect,QRegion::Ellipse);

    qDebug() << region->boundingRect().size();

    m_bouton1->setMask(*region);

    QVBoxLayout *login_form= new QVBoxLayout;

    login_form->addWidget(m_bouton);
    login_form->addWidget(m_bouton1);

    setLayout(login_form);
    setWindowTitle("Button test");
    //setWindowIcon(QIcon("icone.png"));        

    // Connexion du clic du bouton à la fermeture de l'application
    QObject::connect(m_bouton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changerFen()));
    QObject::connect(m_bouton1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(changerFen()));
}

void MyFenetre::changerFen()
{
    int f = 1;
    emit askDisplayFen(f);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change rectangular Qt button to round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734319/change-rectangular-qt-button-to-round)

Comment: its actually the test of this link, but its not working

Comment: Alright, I retracted the Vote. Please add this info to the question prevent further close votes :).

Comment: thanks you can check its already done , I edited my post :)

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use masks? Using the second answer (stylesheets) from the link would be way easier if you are just going for round buttons.

Comment: I'm actually trying the two methods , the stylesheets one , is the next that I'll try to see the result of it , this one seems to be good too , but it need some math calculation to find the right size , and that is not easy to do , from the first try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the size of the window is too small with respect to the sum of the sizes of both windows, so if you are going to establish a fixed size you should calculate it correctly, in this case, do it after adding the buttons.

Also I will improve the code since you are abusing the dynamic memory, for example `QRect` is not necessary to create a pointer since only one copy is needed, the same for `QRegion`.

**myfenetre.h**

```
#ifndef MYFENETRE_H
#define MYFENETRE_H

#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;

class MyFenetre : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyFenetre(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyFenetre();
signals:
    void askDisplayFen(float f);
private slots:
    void changerFen();
private:
    QPushButton *m_bouton;
    QPushButton *m_bouton1;
};

#endif // MYFENETRE_H
```

**myfenetre.cpp**

```
#include "myfenetre.h"

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MyFenetre::MyFenetre(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    m_bouton = new QPushButton("Salut");
    m_bouton->setFont(QFont("Comic Sans MS", 14));

    m_bouton1 = new QPushButton("Boutton RounD (*)");
    m_bouton1->setFixedSize(200, 200);
    QRect rect(QPoint(), m_bouton1->size());
    rect.adjust(10, 10, -10, -10);
    QRegion region(rect,QRegion::Ellipse);
    m_bouton1->setMask(region);

    QVBoxLayout *login_form= new QVBoxLayout(this);
    login_form->addWidget(m_bouton);
    login_form->addWidget(m_bouton1);

    setLayout(login_form);
    setWindowTitle("Button test");

    setFixedSize(300, minimumHeight());
    // Connexion du clic du bouton à la fermeture de l'application
    connect(m_bouton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyFenetre::changerFen);
    connect(m_bouton1, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyFenetre::changerFen);
}

MyFenetre::~MyFenetre()
{

}

void MyFenetre::changerFen()
{
    int f = 1;
    emit askDisplayFen(f);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is helpfull :)

Comment: @MadihaHarifi 
If you review I have added more improvements than indicated in my answer. In C ++, memory management is important.

Comment: Yes I exactly pay attention to this case , its actually much important , I guess either in the compilation time ?

Comment: @MadihaHarifi Forget the compilation time, that's irrelevant since it's done once. The bad handling of the memory brings problems at the moment of the execution.

Comment: You are right , the most problems that I've got while building c++ programs were about the memory use .